# Change a pivot point of the nested svg using d3.js

Tags: d3.js, svg

How could I change a pivot point of the nested `svg` using `d3.js`?

I tried to use `text-anchor` and `alignment-baseline` but it does not work for the `svg` (while works for the `text`).

```js
debugger;
var svg = d3.select("#drawRegion")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", "100%")
  .attr("height", "100%");
svg.append("rect")
  .attr("x", "0")
  .attr("y", "0")
  .attr("width", "100%")
  .attr("height", "100%")
  .attr("fill", "yellow");

const buttonSvg = svg
  .append("svg");
buttonSvg
  .attr("x", "50%")
  .attr("y", "50%")
  .attr("width", "50%")
  .attr("height", "20%")
  .attr("alignment-baseline", "middle")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle");

const rectAroundText = buttonSvg
  .append("rect");
rectAroundText
  .attr("fill", "yellowgreen")
  .attr("width", "100%")
  .attr("height", "100%");

const textMiddleX = 50;
const textMiddleY = 50;

const testText = svg
  .append("text");
testText
  .attr("x", textMiddleX + "%")
  .attr("y", textMiddleY + "50%")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("alignment-baseline", "central")
  .attr("x", "50%")
  .attr("y", "50%")
  .attr("fill", "#000")
  .classed("scalingText", true)
  .text("svdfv");

const textBox = testText.node().getBBox();

/*rectAroundText
 .attr("x", textBox.x)
  .attr("y", textBox.y)
  .attr("width", textBox.width)
  .attr("height", textBox.height);*/
```

```css
#drawRegion {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.scalingText {
  font-size: 400%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .scalingText {
    font-size: 300%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .scalingText {
    font-size: 200%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .scalingText {
    font-size: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="drawRegion">

</div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please embed your code as a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of including it as a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `alignment-baseline` defines vertical text position in relation to a parent element. Since structural elements like `<svg>` or `<g>` are not locatable and therefore do not have a text baseline, it cannot be used for `<text>` elements. Use [`dominant-baseline`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/text.html#DominantBaselineProperty) instead. - Chrome allows the use of `alignment-baseline` for `<text>`, but that is in violation of to the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/text.html#AlignmentBaselineProperty).
2. In the SVG 1.1 spec `alignment-baseline` and `dominant-baseline` are not inheritable. SVG 2 explicitely changes that for `dominant-baseline`, but it is not yet implemented everywhere. Best use a CSS rule that targets (or use a presentation attribute on) text elements directly. `text-anchor` is inheritable and works as expected.
3. Value `central` is meant to be used for ideographic scripts. For Latin, you should use `middle` to align to the middle of the x-height.